# Jquery: Lightswitch = on, then have an If statement seeing if the lightswitch is on, why isn't this working?

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement

Why isn't this code working?
How can I make lightswitch = ON or OFF, then test whether it's ON or OFF later on? Can I do this without dealing with changing Classes or ID's?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').click(function(){
         var lightswitch = ON;

         if (lightswitch == ON) {
            alert('LIGHTSWITCH IS ON.')
                } else {
                alert('OFF.')
                }

          })
})
```

Comment: Is `ON` some sort of variable you've defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably no variable called ON. You could use a boolean value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function() {
        var lightswitch = true;
        if (lightswitch) {
            alert('LIGHTSWITCH IS ON.')
        } else {
            alert('OFF.')
        }
    });
});
```

or a string value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function() {
        var lightswitch = 'ON';
        if (lightswitch == 'ON') {
            alert('LIGHTSWITCH IS ON.')
        } else {
            alert('OFF.')
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously setting a local variable to a hardocoded value followed immediately by an if statement testing the value is not very useful. You could use a global variable which will be set to different values:

```
var lightswitch = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function() {
        if (lightswitch) {
            alert('LIGHTSWITCH IS ON.')
        } else {
            alert('OFF.')
        }
    });
});
```

then you could set `lightswitch = false;` on some other part of your code.